# Implement a sum formula in C

Tags: c, algorithm, sum, formula

So, i need to implement this formula in C:

[image]

Where n is entered by the user and must be >= 1. *Ci* is the i-th digit of the number *n* with *k* digits, and *Ci* with the line is the complement of *Ci* (digit + complement = 9).
For example, the number 21262 fulfills this equation because:

**21262** = 7^5 + 8^4 + 7^3 + 3^2 + 7^1 = 16807 + 4096 + 343 + 9 + 7 = **21262**

I've tried making an algorithm and turning it into a C program, but when I execute, something goes wrong. I'm having trouble formulating the loop that does the k-i+1 power.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
int n, t, k, c, i, s, power, j;
do {
    printf("Enter n = ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
} while (n < 1);

t = n;                    // Here we save the value of n, and operate with t
k = 0;                          // k counts the number of digits 
while (t > 0) {
    t = t / 10;      
    k++;                        // k = number of digits
}                                
t = n;
s = 0;

for (i = 1; i <= k; i++) {            // Starts the sum from i to k
    c = 9 - t % 10;                   // Complements the digits
    power = 1;

    for (j = 1; j <= k-i+1; j++)      // Start of loop that powers th number
        power = c * power;
    s = s + power;
    t = t / 10;
}

if (s == n)
    printf("The number fulfills the equation");
else
    printf("The number doesn't fulfill the equation");
return 0;
}
```

As you can see, I tried solving the power problem by making a loop that multiplies c complement by itself k-i+1 times. But something's not right. Please help!

Comment: you read the number from left to right instead of  from right to left

Comment: for readability by us humans, please consistently indent the code.  In general, indent after EVERY opening brace '{' and un-indent before every closing brace '}'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you read from right to left, the power should be `i` and not `k - i + 1`

```
#include<stdio.h>


int main() {
    int n, t, k, c, i, s, power, j;
    do {
        printf("Enter n = ");
        scanf("%d", &n);
    } while (n < 1);

    t = n;                    // Here we save the value of n, and operate with t
    k = 0;                          // k counts the number of digits
    while (t > 0) {
        t = t / 10;
        k++;                        // k = number of digits
    }
    t = n;
    s = 0;

    for (i = 1; i <= k; i++) {            // Starts the sum from i to k
        c = 9 - (t % 10);                   // Complements the digits
        power = 1;

        for (j = 1; j <= i; j++)      // Start of loop that powers th number
            power = c * power;
        s = s + power;
        t = t / 10;
    }

    if (s == n)
        printf("The number fulfills the equation");
    else
        printf("The number doesn't fulfill the equation");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works now. But I don't understand how it is i, and not k-i+1. How should I interpret this formula?

Comment: for example if n is 12345, for i = 1 you have `t % 10` = 5, your loop is from the right not from the left

Comment: Oh, right. But how could I know it's i? I think I wouldn't be able to conclude it's i even if I knew that I should change it

Comment: If it helps you understand it better, you could make the outer loop `for (i = k; i >= 1; i--)` and the inner loop `for (j = 1; j <= k-i+1; j++)`.

Answer (score 1):

You my use pow(b,p) function under `<math.h>` header file. It may reduce your work. You need not use the inner loop , use this code instead of the inner loop

```
power = pow(c,i);
```

This code may like this-

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>


int main() {
    int n, t, k, c, i, s, power, j;
    do {
        printf("Enter n = ");
        scanf("%d", &n);
    } while (n < 1);

    t = n;                    // Here we save the value of n, and operate with t
    k = 0;                          // k counts the number of digits
    while (t > 0) {
        t = t / 10;
        k++;                        // k = number of digits
    }
    t = n;
    s = 0;

    for (i = 1; i <= k; i++) {            // Starts the sum from i to k
        c = 9 - (t % 10);                   // Complements the digits
        power = 1;

        power = pow(c,i);       // multiply the c by i th time by the pow(b,p) function under math.h.
        s = s + power;
        t = t / 10;
    }

    if (s == n)
        printf("The number fulfills the equation");
    else
        printf("The number doesn't fulfill the equation");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i tried a different approach to your question and it works fine... i think it may be useful to you, so i'm posting it:

> **Note:** I used a function to calculate number of digits in the entered value and also included `math.h` file to use the function `pow()`

so here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>//math.h to use pow() function

int num_digits(int n); //the sub function to caluclate number of digits

int main()
{
    int n,c,t,t1,to_add,ans=0,d,i;

    printf("enter number: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    t=t1=n;
    d=num_digits(n); //function called

    for(i=1;i<=d;i++)
    {
        t=t1%10;
        c=9-t;
        to_add=pow(c,i); //pow()  used here
        ans=ans+to_add;
        t1=t1/10;
        printf("%d\n",t1);
    }

    if(ans==n)
        printf("condition fulfilled!\n");
    else
        printf("condition not fulfilled");

    return 0;
} //main function ends here

int num_digits(int n) //function to caluclate number of digits
{
    int i,c;
    c=n;
    for(i=1;c>10;i=i+1)
        {
            c=n/pow(10,i); //pow() even used here
        }
    return i;
}
```

and by the way your question is quite challenging :)

-thankyou